# Why do std::begin() and std::end() work with fixed arrays, but not with dynamic arrays?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I can't understand why the `std::begin()` function doesn't work when it is given an `int * arr` pointer, but it works with an `int arr[]` array.

This code doesn't work:

```
int *arr = new int[5]{ 1,2,3,4,5 };

if (find(begin(arr),end(arr),5)!=end(arr))
{
    cout << "found";
}
```

This code does work:

```
int arr2[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

if (find(begin(arr2),end(arr2),5)!=end(arr2))
{
    cout << "found";
}
```

Comment: Because the pointer `int *arr ` doesn't have the information needed to support the functionality of the begin and end functions. `int arr2[5]` does have that information because it isn't a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::(c)begin()` and `std:(c)end()` are explicitly overloaded to work with fixed-sized array types.  Information about the size of the arrays is not lost, as the sizes are part of the array types themselves.  An implementation of these overloads may look something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t N>
T* begin(T (&arr)[N])
{
    return arr;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
const T* cbegin(const T (&arr)[N])
{
    return arr;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
T* end(T (&arr)[N])
{
    return arr + N;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
const T* cend(const T (&arr)[N])
{
    return arr + N;
}
```

Thus, `std::begin(arr2)` and `std::end(arr2)` are perfectly valid only when `arr2` is an `int[N]` fixed-size array type.  The compiler can deduce values for the `T` and `N` template parameters based on the type of fixed array being passed in, eg:

```
int arr2[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

if (find(
    begin(arr2), // deduces T=int, N=5, thus calls std::begin<int,5>(arr2)
    end(arr2), // deduces T=int, N=5, thus calls std::end<int,5>(arr2)
    5)
    != end(arr2) // deduces T=int, N=5, thus calls std::end<int,5>(arr2)
    )
{
    cout << "found";
}
```

Conversely, there is simply no way to provide similar **1-parameter** overloads for an `int*` pointer, as there is no information about the size of the array being pointed at (or even whether an array is even being pointed at) for `std::end()` to return a valid iterator to the end of the array:

```
template<typename T>
T* begin(T *arr)
{
    return arr; // OK
}

template<typename T>
const T* cbegin(const T *arr)
{
    return arr; // OK
}

template<typename T>
T* end(T *arr)
{
    return arr + N; // NOT OK, WHAT IS N SUPPOSED TO BE?!?
}

template<typename T>
const T* cend(const T *arr)
{
    return arr + N; // NOT OK, WHAT IS N SUPPOSED TO BE?!?
}
```

However, you *can* provide your own **2-parameter** overloads <sup>1</sup>, so you can explicitly pass in the dynamic array size for `N`, eg:

```cpp
namespace std
{
    template<typename T>
    T* begin(T *arr, size_t N)
    {
        return arr;
    }

    template<typename T>
    const T* cbegin(const T *arr, size_t N)
    {
        return arr;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T* end(T *arr, size_t N)
    {
        return arr + N;
    }

    template<typename T>
    const T* cend(const T *arr, size_t N)
    {
        return arr + N;
    }
}
```

```cpp
int *arr = new int[5]{ 1,2,3,4,5 };

if (find(
    begin(arr,5), // deduces T=int, explicit N=5, thus calls std::begin<int>(arr2,5)
    end(arr2,5), // deduces T=int, explicit N=5, thus calls std::end<int>(arr2,5)
    5)
    != end(arr2,5) // deduces T=int, explicit N=5, thus calls std::end<int>(arr2,5)
    )
{
    cout << "found";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/qZwMO1)

<sup>1: you ARE NOT allowed to add new functions to the `std` namespace, but you ARE allowed to add custom overloads for *existing* standard functions. `std::swap()` is an common example of that, though utilizing [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) is generally a better choice than extending the `std` namespace.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't work because `int *arr` isn't an array, it's a pointer. It happens to point to the first element of an array, but it's pointing to the element, not the array. Once it's converted to a pointer, the length information is lost.

Pedantic note: It's not *completely* lost, as it's actually hidden in an implementation-specific manner such that the allocator knows how much to free when you later `delete[]` it, but that's not exposed to anything *but* the allocator, and it's often not equal to the actual size requested, due to allocator alignment requirements, so it's not useful here.

Answer (score 0):

The [std::begin docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) :

> ```
> template< class C >
> auto begin( C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin());
> ```
>
> Returns an iterator to the beginning of the given **container c or array**. These templates rely on C::begin() having a reasonable implementation.

`int *arr` is not an array, but a pointer, while `int arr2[5]` **is** an array.

Comment: You're technically correct ([the best kind of correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo)), but this doesn't provide any insight on *why* `begin` can't handle pointers.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat As I understand the doc, *only* "container or array" is accepted. If the docs would like to forbid invalid types then the planet has not enough paper.

Comment: I agree that the docs clearly forbid using `begin` & `end` on pointers. My point is that there is a reason behind this limitation, and I suggest explaining it to the OP.