# range - based loop traversal in array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, range-based-loop

#### ****The code I tried to implement is : ****

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n, k;
   cout << "Enter the number of elements: \n";
   cin >> n;

   cout << "Enter the array: \n";
   int *arr = new int[n];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

   cout << "Enter k: " << endl;
   cin >> k;

   cout << "Elements less than k: " << endl;
   for (int x : arr)
   {
       if (x < k)
            cout << x << endl;
   }

   
   delete[] arr;

   return 0;
}
```

> **The error it's throwing is :** error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope     for (int x : arr)                  ^

The array is dynamically allocated. Takes elements and var 'k' as input and ideally returns the elements which are less than k.
first loop is traditional for loop
second one is range based, and the problem is in that

I tried taking reference '&x' in there to but the problem persists

**problem :**

```
error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
    for (int x : arr)
                 ^
```

Comment: `arr` is a pointer.  It is *not* an array.  There is no "size information" associated with a pointer -- it is just a pointer, no more, no less.

Comment: You are probably looking for std::vector for arr.

Comment: `int *arr = new int[n];` --> `std::vector<int> arr(n);`

Comment: See the two dupes: [Why doesn't C++ support range based for loop for dynamic arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363608/why-doesnt-c-support-range-based-for-loop-for-dynamic-arrays) and [Why do std::begin() and std::end() work with fixed arrays, but not with dynamic arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57827935/why-do-stdbegin-and-stdend-work-with-fixed-arrays-but-not-with-dynamic)

Comment: For range based for loops to work the type you loop over must have a `begin()` and `end()` method that return iterators to the begin and end of your container. As you can see you only have an `int*` and that has no way of nowing what its "end" is, it is just a pointer into memory. That's why people tell you to use `std::vector`, it solves multiple things : you will have no new/delete needed (new/delete hardly ever should appear in current C++ code),  You will not have an owning raw pointer (also not recommmended in C++) and you will get your `begin()` and `end()` from `std::vector`